# SQL Fastest way to Group records based on Thresholds

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

My records are in a temporary table having three columns :

1. Column1 : ID (Bigint)
2. Column2 : CreationDateTime (dateTime)
3. Column3 : Volume (Float)

The records are sorted based on CreationDateTime.
I need to pick the records from the table where Sum of Volume is equal to THRESHOLD1 and then the same for Threshold2.

One way is to add a new Column to the table which has the sum of Volume for the previous records. for example :

ID - CreationDateTime - Volume - SUM

1  - 20/07/2012       -  10    - 10

2  - 21/07/2012       -  12    - 22

3  - 22/07/2012       -  7     - 29

and then Select * from temp where Sum >= Threshold But the calculation of the sum is not the fastest way.

I was wondering if anyone can suggest a better way for doing the above.

I'm using SQL server 2008 and I can also use CLR if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using a recursive CTE, which will likely be the fastest:

```
select @i=min(ID) from @temp

;with a as 
( 
    select ID, Volume, Volume as RunningTotal 
    from @temp
    where ID=@i 

    union all 
    select b.ID, b.Volume, b.Volume + a.RunningTotal as RunningTotal 
    from @temp b 
        inner join a 
            on b.ID=a.ID+1 

) 
select * from a
```

Some links related to running totals:

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/runningtotal/

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3112381/SQL-Server-Calculating-Running-Totals-Subtotals-and-Grand-Total-Without-a-Cursor.htm

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1686/calculate-running-totals-using-sql-server-cross-joins/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/transactsql/thread/1b4d87cb-ec77-4455-af48-bf7dae50ab87

Computed Column using a function:

```
create function dbo.fn_VolumeRunningTotal 
{ 
    @dt datetime 
} 
returns int 
as  
begin 
    declare @total int 
    select @total = sum(volume) 
    from dbo.MyVolumeTable 
    where CreationDateTime <= @dt 

    return @total 
end
```

Computed Column formula:

```
dbo.fn_VolumeRunningTotal(CreationDateTime)
```

Select statements:

```
select * from dbo.MyVolumnTable where RunningTotal <= @Threshold1
```

Comment: Would you please also ad the last reply ? Because I want to check them as well. thx

Comment: @Asha - added back the references

Answer (score 1):

try this solution:

you can find the running total just by self joining tables and group by

```
with cte as(
select T2.ID, T2.CreationDateTime,SUM(T1.Volume) [SUM]
from test_table T1 join  test_table T2
on T1.id<=T2.id
group by T2.id, T2.CreationDateTime)
select * from cte where [SUM]>= Threshold
```